# Exclude Files/Folders from Docker Base Image

Tags: docker, security, dockerfile, dockerignore

We are using Twistlock to look for security vulnerabilities in docker images.

Unfortunately, we are seeing some security issues in docker base images (For ex: Alpine, Logstash, Custom Built Docker Images). As a fix, we continue to upgrade to latest version available. Unluckily, for the Custom Built Docker Images too, we don't have any control other than consuming it.

Just wondering if there could be a way to exclude the files/folders inside the docker base image, like below

```
FROM XXX:/logstash.7.6.0
***Add Exclusions for files/folders inside logstash***
VOLUME /tmp
ENV XXX
USER logstash
```

I came across usage of dockerignore file, but I believe they are used to ignore the files/folders from the current project and not from the base docker image.

Could someone share some inputs here?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually remove most of the things that you want by adding this:
**RUN rm -rf [path]** or **RUN yum remove -y [package_name]** (this instruction is for images being based on centos) instructions to your docker file after **FROM** instruction.

**Warning!** these remove operations can very likely cause serious problems for your images.

Example:

```
FROM XXX:/logstash.7.6.0

USER root # change user to root in order to get full permission
RUN rm -rf /fileX /dirY 
RUN yum remove -y packageX

VOLUME /tmp
ENV XXX
USER logstash
```

Also check this [page](https://github.com/BretFisher/ama/issues/17#issuecomment-400163774). It includes some security recommendations.